# Modifying sf::ConvexShape hitbox in sfml

Tags: sfml

I am trying to modify the hitbox of a convex shape in sfml in order to accurately test for intersection between a projectile that I have. I cannot seem to figure out how to modify the bounding box of my shape in order to accurately follow the outline of my shape. [This is what the current hit box looks like based on the global bounds of my convex shape.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsvhg.png) I was wondering what others have done to get an accurate representation for the hitbox of shapes in sfml? Thanks for any help.

Comment: the bounding box can be defined by the two corners `min(x0..xn), min(y0..yn)` `max(x0..xn), max(y0..yn)`